# como accedo al elemento dentro del array VB.NET?

Tags: array, vb.net

Tengo un array que se forma a partir de una cadeda de string.

```
Dim cadena as string = "texto1-texto2-texto3"  
Dim miarray as Array = cadena.Split("-")
```

Esto me da como resultado un array,

```
miarray{0(texto1),1(texto2),2(texto3)}
```

Como accedo u obtengo el elemento 1 del array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el modo simple de la siguiente forma:

```
miarray(1) 'Esto devuelve el elemento 1 del array
```

Otra manera de obtenerlo es con la opción [`GetValue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.array.getvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) de la siguiente forma:

```
miarray.GetValue(1)
```

Comment: esa opcion no aparece, uso VS 2012 professional.

Comment: @Manny Editada la respuesta

Comment: usando el modo simple solo puedo acceder a la posicion 0, pero a la posicion 1 y 2 no entra, por ejemplo yo quiero hacer esto if miarray(1) = "texto2" then pero no entra al if, no se que pase ahi.

Comment: @Manny Entonces tienes que hacer un bucle y recorrer todo el array haciendo esa comprobación. Esto es una cosa totalmente diferente a lo que estas preguntando.